# Using Cylindrical coordinates with Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}],
  Blue, Thick,
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 0}}],
  Line[{{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 0}, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 1}}],
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 1}],
  Arrow[Table[0.5 {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, Pi/4, Pi/24}]],
  Text[Style["x", Black, 14], {2.1, 0, 0}],
  Text[Style["y", Black, 14], {0, 2.1, 0}],
  Text[Style["z", Black, 14], {0, 0, 2.1}],
  Text[Style["\[Pi]/4", Black, 14], {0.6, 0.2, 0}],
  Text[Style["2", Black, 14], {0.7, 0.9, 0}],
  Text[Style["1", Black, 14], {1.6, 1.4, 0.5}],
  Text[Style["(2, \[Pi]/4, 1)", Black, 14], {1.4, 1.4, 1.2}]
  }]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

Suppose that I wish to use cylindrical coordinates, for example, `Line[{{0,0,0},{2,Pi/4,0}}]` instead of `Line[{{0,0,0},{Sqrt[2],Sqrt[2],0}}]`. How would I go about that?

And, suppose I wanted to use cylindrical coordinates everywhere in my code. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One easy solution is to write your graphics-primitives as usual but using cylindrical coordinates instead.

```
primitives = Table[
  {Hue[z], Arrow[{{0, 0, 5 z}, {1, 2 Pi z, 5 z}}]}, {z, 0, 1, .05}
  ];
```

And before you display them inside a `Graphics3D`, you map all 3D points from cylindrical to Cartesian

```
mapping[{r_, theta_, z_}] := {r Cos[theta], r Sin[theta], z};
Graphics3D[primitives /. point : {_, _, _} :> mapping[point]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### Edit

Davids comment:

> Can you explain this line: `Graphics3D[primitives /. point : {_, _, _} :> mapping[point]]`? The part I don't understand is `point : {_, _, _} :>`

The `primitives` are all kind of graphic drawing commands and I assume that all 3d vectors like `{1,Pi,2}` are indeed points given in cylindrical coordinates. What I want to do is to replace every point by its Cartesian counterpart.

So what I tell *Mathematica* is to replace every `point` that has the form of a list with 3 elements. This is written as

```
point:{_,_,_}
```

If haven't seen the `:` operator then please read the documentation of [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html).

The other operator that seems to confuse you is `:>`. Don't be afraid, it doesn't bite. It is just a normal rule that you can use for replacement of expressions and it is the good friend of the well known `->`. The difference between them is very simple. When you write

```
expr /. lhs -> rhs
```

then `rhs` is evaluated before it is replaced. When you use `:>` instead, then `rhs` is not evaluated. Sounds complicated? Please study the following very simple example. Try to think about what you would expect as result before evaluating it. Tip: `HoldForm` will not evaluate something. Therefore `HoldForm[1-1]` will not be evaluated to 0.

```
HoldForm[a] /. a -> (a + 1 - 1)

HoldForm[a] /. a :> (a + 1 - 1)
```

Finally, in this specific example (and indeed in many other examples too), I could have used `->` as well and the outcome would be the same. On the other hand, a very unexpected thing would have happened if you had defined

```
point = {0, 0, 0};
```

somewhere in your notebook. And to give you another reason to use [:>](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html), look at how beautifully *green* the last `point` is highlighted when you use it

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you explain this line: `Graphics3D[primitives /. point : {_, _, _} :> mapping[point]]`? The part I don't understand is `point : {_, _, _} :>`.

Comment: For `mapping` you could also use: `transform = 
 CoordinateTransformData["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"]`

Comment: @chuy I explicitly didn't use it because I wouldn't have been able to explain why this doesn't work: `CoordinateTransform["Cylindrical" -> "Cartesian", {0, 0, 0}]`. My initial version contained `CoordinateTransform` and I was really surprised that it choked upon every point where `r` is zero. Any clues?

Comment: @David See my edit at the end of the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @halirutan Those are singular points. If you use the `"Mapping"` form it doesn't perform the check to see if the point obeys the coordinate range assumptions for that chart. Similarly `CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, 0, 0}]` would give the same message.